# Does an Operator Exist to Convert String to bytes?

Tags: mongodb

When execute distinct operator on a field I got below result

```
> db.customer.distinct("lastname")
[ "Matthews", "Matthews" ]
```

`Matthews` is duplicated. Naturally thought must they have diff bytes although the display is same. But I cannot find how to convert a String to bytes just like in java

```
jshell> "abc".getBytes()
$7 ==> byte[3] { 97, 98, 99 }
```

I only find `strLenBytes` operator

```
> db.customer.aggregate(
... {$project:{ _id:0,lastname:1,length:{$strLenBytes:"$lastname"}}}
... )
{ "lastname" : "Matthews", "length" : 8 }
{ "lastname" : "Matthews", "length" : 11 }

> db.customer.aggregate(
...     {$project:{ _id:0,lastname:1,length:{$strLenCP:"$lastname"}}}
... )
{ "lastname" : "Matthews", "length" : 8 }
{ "lastname" : "Matthews", "length" : 9 }
```

So does exist some operator or manner could directly convert String to bytes in mongo?

[image]

Comment: No "casting" is allowed at all in the aggregation framework. If you need to fix things like this then you need to actually loop results and convert in code. It's likely that [`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/) however will report these to be the same size. That's the intent. The `.distinct()` method cannot tell the difference, but the aggregation framework ( with said operator ) "should" be able to do so.

Comment: You could use JavaScript's `String.prototype.charCodeAt()` while iterating over the string. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: @CodeCaster as for this case, just use `strLenBytes` could tell why `Matthews ` is duplicated .  But I also want to know the detail info--where the different are?  In this case I know one String have extra bytes at head -- that is `[-17, -69, -65] + "Matthews"`, so with this info I could investigate this kind of string how to generated. And now I have to use `spring data mongo ` to query them first  then output them by `str.getBytes()` .  I just feel it is a little trouble .

Comment: To what end though? As you can see the `$strLenBtyes` reports a different size, which is of course true. But like I said `$strLenCP` "should" report the same size. So you "could" use that to "group" and then collect the records that actually have differing encodings. If that is what you are asking?

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry I do not to express it clearly.  To put it simply, if I want to know the bytes of a string in mongo , e.g. `{"lastname":"Matthews"}`,does exist some manner could directly output the bytes directly in mongo shell. Do not trouble use java driver to query the result first then call str.getBytes() to know the bytes of this string. In addition in the case even use '$strLenCP'  they still have diff size.

Comment: You already have been answered on that. No there is not. The `$strLenCP` output is interesting, but I'm inclined to think you are not telling the "whole" truth here, and that in fact these strings should actually look visibly different ( to you that is, and there is no way we can tell from here ). What we keep coming back to though that you are yet to address is *"Do you need to convert these to the same code page?". If that is the goal, then you need to loop the collection in external code.

Comment: And the general ask is *"What is your actual question?"*. No there is not a shell function. No there is not an aggregate function. Either do the loop and convert or explain to us "beyond" the NO answer you already have, then what do you really need to do? If not simply loop and convert like you have been told already.

Comment: The best I can suggest without more input is you could possibly do `db.customer.aggregate({ "$redact": { "$cond": [{ "$ne": [ { "$subtract": [ { "$strLenBytes": "$lastname" }, { "$strLenCP": "$lastname" } ] }, 0 ] }, "$$KEEP", "$$PRUNE" ] } })` to identify those strings that differ in length and therefore use a codepage with multiple bytes. Those you can then loop externally to convert.

Comment: @NeilLunn because these diff strings actually look visibly same, at least in mongo shell and compass gui. (Please see the image of this post)  so I should to convert it to bytes explicitly to know the  real diffs and could to investigate the reason for this diff -- that is how the abnoraml String  generated? Does it generated by somebody insert/update it manually , or from post commit like this.